# React, Components and views

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm making a site that has **two components** : **the header**, **the footer** **and** between them there are the **views** like the home page or other pages.

the Homepage:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Logo from "../../img/logo.png"
import '../../styles/Home.css';
import pic from '../../img/pic.jpg';
import { Divider } from 'material-ui';


const style = {
  margin: 4,

};

class HomePage extends Component {


  render() {
    return (
   <div className="Home">
        <div className="parallax">
            <div className="Box">
              <img src={Logo}/>
                <div id="buttons">
                  <RaisedButton className="button" label="    Download...  " primary={true} style={style} />
                  <RaisedButton className="button" label="Discover Features" primary={true} style={style} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div className="info">

        </div>
   </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

and his css:

```
.Home{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.Box{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding:  20vh;

}

.parallax{
        background-image: url("../img/pic.jpg");
        height: 100vh;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
}

.info{
    background-color:  #1e8449 ;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

the problem is that in the Home Page i have a parallax img and green div in a div (className="Home") but when i analyze it on google chrome **it seem that the green div and the parallax img are not in the same div.**

Comment: where is the green div in your code?

Comment: is one with the class "info"

Comment: it is in the same div https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/118470/

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: with vh i know how to make it but i don't know the reason why with percetual it doesn't work